# How Do I Finish The Edge...hardwood floor landing

Tags: hardwood-floor

this is my first post.  Many more to come, I'm sure. I tried to post a photo but it's too large to upload. How do you finish hardwood on a landing that is open to the room?  I thought I'd edge it with a piece of 3 1/2" bullnose but it looks funny.  Is there a trim piece I can buy that is thinner than a 3 1/2" bullnose?

Comment: The bullnose looks funny? Explain

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A photo would be really helpful; try to reduce it and then post it. If not, post a URL to the photo and someone will be along to edit it in. (And hope to see many more from you.)